# CodenameOne - using terse REST api for nestoria-based demo doesn't compile

Tags: codenameone

I like the look of the terse REST api as highlighted in the 8th Feb CodenameOne blog (https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-rest-calls.html) but I am unsure how to add arguments like you do with ConnectionRequest addArgument("key","value"). Using the nestoria JSON example as a start (https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/JSONParser.html) I have changed it to this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("encoding", "json");
json.put("listing_type", "buy");
json.put("page","1");
json.put("country", "uk");
json.put("place_name", "birmingham");
Map<String, Object> jsonData = Rest.get("http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api").
                contentType("application/json").
                body(json).
                acceptJson().
                getAsJsonMap();
```

However, at the line:

```
body(json).
```

I get the error "body(java.lang.String) in 'com.codename1.io.rest.RequestBuilder' cannot be applied to (ca.weblite.codename1.json.JSONObject)". What is the correct way of adding arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body` method accepts a String so this will compile `body(json.toString()).`

However, that specific call isn't a POST call so a body with JSON doesn't make sense for that API. That specific call accepts regular get arguments so what you probably wanted to do is this:

```
Map<String, Object> jsonData = Rest.get("https://api.nestoria.co.uk/api").
               jsonContent().
               queryParam("encoding", "json").
               queryParam("listing_type", "buy").
               queryParam("page","1").
               queryParam("country", "uk").
               queryParam("place_name", "birmingham").
               getAsJsonMap();
```

Also notice I removed the `contentType` entry and `acceptJson` as both can be expressed via `jsonContent`. Also fixed URL to https which should be the default...

Comment: Hello, I have added the .toString() call but now get a different error - "Incompatible types. Found 'com.codename1.io.rest.Response<java.util.Map>' required 'java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>'". 
If I change the return type from `Map<String, Object>` to `Response<Map>` I don't get any compile errors and the code runs but even though I get a 200 response code there is no data returned? I have run the PropertyCross demo to confirm that there is data to return.

Comment: I don't understand why you had the body() entry in the first place for this specific API? I edited my answer with something that should work